# Wordpress - how to add Class on <li> in wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: wordpress, menuitem, listitem

I need each li from my menu to have different class. In `wp-admin/menus/screen options` it is possible to add CSS classes but when I add class "one" in return I get `li class="one menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-18 one"` , when I need `li class="one"`,`li class="two"`,`li class="three"`,`li class="four"` to target it with my CSS. There has to be some other way maby through adding some custom function?

Comment: It is going to be complicated to add the classes the way you want. It's most probably easier to use the [`_nth-child` pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child) in CSS.

Comment: Also, why do the additional classes WordPress adds bother you? They don't interfere with your CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`nav_menu_css_class`** to add custom class see here for more details http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class

Answer (score 0):

HERE [WordPress add custom class in wp_nav_menu links](http://sdtuts.com/wordpress-add-custom-class-in-wp_nav_menu-links/)

OR you can add class  Link from admin panel

Go to YOURSITEURL/wp-admin/nav-menus.php

open SCREEN OPTIONS make checked "CSS CLASSES" then you will see "CSS Classes (optional)"